# Why my /etc/motd doesn't show the welcome message at login?

Tags: motd

I have a Debian/Linux virtual machine in VirtualBox.

```
# uname -a
Linux debian 4.19.0-14-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.171-2 (2021-01-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux

# vi /etc/motd

##########################
Hi, welcome to the server!
##########################


~                                                                                                                                                            
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
"/etc/motd" 6 lines, 84 characters written
:wq!
```

When I exit terminal and login as root, the message in `/etc/motd` doesn't appear.

```
root@debian:~#
```

How can I make the message appear?

Comment: How do you "_login as root_"? On the text console, using a GUI, via `ssh`, or some other way?

Comment: Using a GUI.  Mate GUI.

Comment: I'm not aware of any GUI that displays `/etc/motd` at login or indeed at any other point

Comment: May be you are correct.  For me I need a simple banner to display the message of the day,  date, machine name and big banner when I open the terminal.  May be I need a cat /etc/motd in /etc/profile.  but I think that this is not the correct way.  Do you think that disabling the GUI makes that my /etc/motd works?

Answer (score 0):

Modern Debian (and many other distro) use `pam_motd` run out of their PAM stack. See this [debian wiki article](https://wiki.debian.org/motd) for more details.

It’s possible that you have a customized PAM environment, or your root user has a ~/.hushlogin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't understand what is PAM and hushlogin.  The referenced article is difficult to understand for me.

Comment: PAM is the Pluggable Authentication Mechanism. And is configured in /etc/pam.d/, each file for a specific service.  So, if you are logging in at the text console, look in /etc/pam.d/login, which is used by the “login” process.  OpenSSH uses /etc/pam.d/sshd and so on.  Typically they include a generic config in the same directory.

Comment: I think that I have PAM configuration.  But I need a step by step solution is possible.  I use a Mate GUI to login for the first time and then I open the terminal session using the menu.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have step by step instructions.  I suggest perusing the man pages for pam.conf to better understand the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the banner in `ssh_config` (or `sshd_config` - it depends on the OS). Usually it is located in `/etc/issue` and everything you put into this issue file will be displayed when you will login through `ssh`.

Comment: I found /etc/ssh_config and /etc/ssh/config file.  I add the banner on both files and nothing happens.

Comment: In debian it should be /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
Add this: Banner /etc/issue
Edit /etc/issue 
Provide what you need, save, exit. Restart sshd service by command: systemctl restart sshd Log out from ssh session and login. Yu should see welcome message.

Comment: I create the banner in /etc/issue.  I get the error, “Failed to restart sshd.service not found.

Comment: systemctl status sshd should display the status of the service
It is strange. Looks like you  do not have sshd installed?

Comment: systemctl status sshd.    Unit sshd.service could not be found.  How can I install sshd service?

Comment: I found on internet how to install ssh service.  Let me try again your recommendation so know if it works this time.

Comment: As root, I type the command su - ricardo, and the Welcome Baner typed in /etc/issue appear perfectly.  But I closed the terminal window and login again as root and as ricardo and nothing happen.  I type the command # systemctl status sshd and I get this:

Comment: ● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enab
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-03-07 13:51:27 AST; 12min ago
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
  Process: 31987 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 31988 (sshd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 2347)
   Memory: 1.1M
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           └─31988 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Comment: So the service is active but the banner in /etc/issue display only one time. :(

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246436/how-to-set-a-dynamic-message-of-the-day-motd-in-debian-jessie-8-2-for-ssh