# alpine update motd on login

Tags: login, alpine-linux, motd

Is there any way to update the `/etc/motd` file on login? The `/etc/profile` and `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` scripts are executed after the motd is already displayed on login so these methods don't work.

I want to add dynamic details about the current IP address and display it in the motd. However, I can't find a way to update the motd before it gets displayed to the user logging in.

Thanks!

Comment: Edit the question to include what you see after login including what is there are a result of `/etc/profile` and the scripts in `/etc/profile.d/`. I can't reproduce what you are seeing in Alpine Linux. What I put in `/etc/motd` appears regardless of what is in those files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a dynamic Message of the Day (motd) in Debian Jessie 8.2 for ssh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246436/how-to-set-a-dynamic-message-of-the-day-motd-in-debian-jessie-8-2-for-ssh)

Answer (score 0):

I had to rethink how to approach this problem.
I was trying to use a script in `/etc/profile.d` to update the `/etc/motd` file.
This was not working because the motd is displayed on login before `/etc/profile.d` scripts are executed - causing motd to be displayed then silently updated by the script after the fact.

I cleared the motd file and had the `/etc/profile.d` script directly echo what I wanted to display on user login instead.